# Asynchronously running C++ and JS code in V8

Tags: javascript, c++, scripting, embedding, v8

I'm currently experimenting with embedding V8 in a project of mine. Since I use libev for listening to sockets and events and want to be able to script events with JS I would want to be able to just run v8 for a short while and then jump back to C++ to check for events and such and then go back to running JS-code. Since I haven't done much script embedding earlier I'm sure there are some clever way that this usually is done in so all ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at the source for [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/), it does exactly what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way I found of doing this is to create setTimeout and clearTimeout functions within JS. setTimeout creates a `ev::Timer` which has a callback that gets called after a certain amount of time. This makes it so that when you call a JS function you continue to execute that until it returns, but that function can set a number of timeouts which aren't called until after you exit the current JS and there hasn't happened any other libev events during the execution, in that case those are handled first (in C++). The limitations of this method is that the coder who writes JS has to remember to not write functions that goes into eternal while-loops or similar. A loop is instead done like this:

```
function repeat() { setTimeout(repeat, 0); }
```